# Conics sections on eliminating xy term

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, conic-sections

Consider $Ax^{2}+By^{2}+Cxy+Dx+Ey+F=0 \space \space (*)$

In the case when $C=1$, find, in terms of the coefficients of (*), the value of the constant $k$ for which the transformation with the matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
k & 1 \\
-1 & k
\end{pmatrix}

reduces (*) to a form with zero $xy$-term.

I let the image point be \begin{pmatrix}
x' \\
y'
\end{pmatrix}

and so the pre-image is

\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{kx'-y'}{k^{2}+1} \\
\frac{x'+ky'}{k^{2}+1}
\end{pmatrix}

Substituting this into (*) and set the coefficient of $xy$-term to zero. I managed to obtain $k=A-B\pm\sqrt{(A-B)^{2}+1}$.

Is there a way to solve this problem using eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Answer (score 1):

We find a matrix $P$ which diagonalizes the symmetric matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}A&\frac C2\\\frac C2&B\end{pmatrix}$. Then, the transformation $\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix}=P\begin{bmatrix} x'\\y'\end{bmatrix}$ eliminates the $xy$-term, because $P^T$ is a multiple of $P^{-1}$ for real symmetric matrices. Recall that the associated quadratic form is $\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix}^TA\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix}$.

Example: Let us consider the ellipse $2x^2+2xy+y^2=1\tag1$ Then $A=\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ with eigen values $\lambda_1=\phi+1$ and $\lambda_2=2-\phi$ and corresponding eigenvectors $v_1=\begin{bmatrix}\phi\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $v_2=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-\phi\end{bmatrix}$. Thus $P=\begin{pmatrix}\phi&1\\1&-\phi\end{pmatrix}$. Now,
$x=\phi x'+ y'$ and $y=x'-\phi y'$ transform the given ellipse to
$(\phi+1)(x')^2+(2-\phi)(y')^2=\frac1{\phi+2}\tag2$
with no cross-term.